# Refer to field value in django admin template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-orm

I would override the admin `change_form` template, inserting a link.
I am able to retrieve the value of a form field (called tag) using

```
{{ adminform.form.tag.value }}
```

So, I can make an url simply:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return popitup('/popup/?id={{adminform.form.tag.value}}')">link</a>
```

But I can't get the value of a field 'id' (primary key of model) non showed in `change_form`, but defined in model.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return popitup('/popup/?id={{adminform.form.id.value}}')">link</a>
```

Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 4):

For a model form `form` you can access the instance being edited with `form.instance`.

So I would try (I haven't tested this to confirm it works):

```
{{ adminform.form.instance.id }}
```